# Does increasing index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset to a larger number hurt query performance? If so, how much, and why?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do a query for to my index, I'm getting the following error:

> "The length of [field_21] field of [82213] doc of [jobs] index has exceeded [10000] - maximum allowed to be analyzed for highlighting. This maximum can be set by changing the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] index level setting. For large texts, indexing with offsets or term vectors is recommended!"

When I increase the `max_analyzed_offset` from 10,000 to 10,000,000, it solves my problem, and the queries are equally as fast. Should I be worried about leaving this setting like this? Would I hit a performance drop off? Or should I use offsets / term vectors? One caveat with using the term vectors, is that they increase the size of the index.

Also, is there a way to disable the highlighting if it contains more than a particular number of characters?

Comment: Did you permanently set the `max_analyzed_offset` value? If so, how? With new indices I have to manually invoke the following REST request to update the `max_analyzed_offset` value:
`PUT /index_name_nere/_settings
{
  "index" : {
    "highlight.max_analyzed_offset" : 10000000
  }
}`

Comment: Yes, I did set the `highlight.max_analyzed_offset` manually through the _settings endpoint. I'm curious if setting this to a higher number will cause performance issues.

Comment: Elasticsearch seemed to also offer another (and possibly better) option to combat these exceptions, without having to increase the index setting of highlight.max_analyzed_offset.   Lets face it, if you can't find a highlight after a million chars, that's a pretty big doc.  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/69016